# Configuring SSTP Client on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn

I have a personal VPS running as my personal VPN server. I can connect to it using openconnect which its server is running inside a docker container or by a reality VLESS config provided by x-ui panel. I also have the sstpc package installed on the VPS. What I want to do is to connect to my VPS through one of the two protocols (openconnect/vless) and have my traffic routed through the sstp connection made by sstpc package. I searched a lot but couldn't find anyone who tried it before. Please help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.